# How to fix problem with z-index and overflow:scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, z-index

code in sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-microservice-4rplf

I got  select and modal components . When I click on select, it unfolds inside modal component and creates scroll.

[image]

I want make it like in the picture below . Display select over modal. I make it by removing overflow:scroll from modal component. But I need to leave overflow:scroll in case modal gets bigger. I think there is a problem with z-index. Could you please help me solve that problem.

[image]

```
.modal-block {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 60% !important;
  max-height: 300px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index: 1111;
}


.select-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1600;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow-y:scroll;` in `.modal-wrapper`and remove `overflow-y: scroll;` and `max-height: 300px;` from `.modal-block`.  Checkout the sandbox link [Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-voice-pmqdw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

If your "Select" tag is coming at the end in the modal then you can do like this:

Class `.modal-block` remove `overflow-y:scroll;`

Class `.modal-body` add `overflow-y:scroll;`

Move .select-wrapper out of .modal-body like this

```
<div class="modal-block">Content</div>
<div class="select-wrapper">SELECT OPTION</div>
```

Comment: I cant move it out of modal, it is a components .

Answer (score 0):

Just a different opinion, I think we could just apply `scroll` effect to the text paragraph instead of the entire modal block. In this way, you can easily set the height of the entire modal block and its child text paragraph as needed.

Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-curran-pzq5j